# Should I use a enumeration in UML when a property can only take two values?

Tags: enums, boolean, uml, enumeration, class-diagram

We have a very concrete case in our UML diagram which is the MeasurementSystem property. It can be either the imperial or metric system and it is quite important. I wondered if I should make this an enumeration named MeasurementSystem which has Imperial and Metric in there. The other option is making it a boolean but it doesn't seem logical since it is not really a true/false situation but I am just wondering about if it is okay anyway.

Comment: I would just say: ban the imperial system. It's only put on top of the metric system and at best can make missiles (and other flying stuff) fail.

Answer (score 2):

**Using an enum** has three main advantages:

- It is closer to the reality and less ambiguous:  it's not about true/false but metric/imperial.
- The alternatives are self-documenting
- If at a later stage you want to use ancient Greek or Roman or Biblic measurement systems, it's easier to expand.

**Using a boolean** `isMetric` is easier to implement but it makes later evolution very difficult, once you have a lot of `if ...  else` rather than `switch case`

Another possibility is to **make a class** `MeasurementSystem` with two specializations `MetricSystem` and `ImperialSystem`.  You then don't have to foresee a lot of `switch case` but you could fully benefit from polymorphism instead.

Comment: The MeasurementSystem class can also do conversions this way.